# Spring batch pass dynamic file name to onSkipInRead

Tags: spring-batch

I want to pass a dynamic file name to onSkipInRead.
example:
      public MySkipListener(@Value("#{jobParameters['file']}") String file) throws IOException {
            bw= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file);
        System.out.println("MySkipListener =========> :"+bw);
      }

```
  @Override
  public void onSkipInRead(Throwable throwable) {
      if (throwable instanceof FlatFileParseException) {
          FlatFileParseException flatFileParseException = (FlatFileParseException) throwable;
          try {
                bw.write(flatFileParseException.getInput()+"; Step Vérifiez les colonnes !!");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              System.err.println("Unable to write skipped line to error file"); }
      }
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: use Throwable to save file name. Catch the exception and save file name to throwable and use it in listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a constructor in your listener with a file and pass the file to it when you define the step. Here is an example:

```
class MySkipListener implements SkipListener<Integer, Integer> {

    private FileWriter fileWriter;

    public MySkipListener(File file) throws IOException {
        this.fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
    }

    // your onSkipInRead method
}
```

Then you pass the job parameter file to your listener when you define the step:

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public Step step(@Value("#{jobParameters['file']}") String file) throws IOException {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            .<Integer, Integer>chunk(5)
            .reader(itemReader())
            .writer(itemWriter())
            .listener(new MySkipListener(new File(file)))
            .build();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Mahoud, I was this message :

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?

Comment: I probably missed `@JobScope` on the step. I edited the answer and it should work fine now.

Comment: Okay and to the job it's correct? I pass null to step?

@Bean
  public Job jobCC5(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilders,
      StepBuilderFactory stepBuilders) throws IOException {
    return jobBuilders.get("jobCC5")
        .start(step1decryptNir(stepBuilders, null)).build();
  }

Comment: Okay bat after creating jar and run it, i don't reiceve file

Comment: private BufferedWriter bw = null;public MySkipListener(File file) throws IOException {bw= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("sftp_cpf_cc5\\fichiers\\env\\xdej_xcc5_cpt_logExeption.csv", true));
 }  @Override public void onSkipInRead(Throwable throwable) { if (throwable instanceof FlatFileParseException) { FlatFileParseException flatFileParseException = (FlatFileParseException) throwable;  try { bw.write(flatFileParseException.getInput()+";bw.newLine();bw.flush(); fileWriter.close();} catch (IOException e) { } } }

Comment: Please edit the question and add code. Code in comments is not readable.

Comment: Okay Mahmoud Thanks !